# ASP.NET External Login Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I currently have a web app in `ASP.NET MVC` using `ASP.NET Identity` for authentication (user/password).

Now i want to shift the authentication to an **external service**. this external service only returns the username (indicating that is authenticated).

How can i tell my web app (and to ASP.NET Identity) that the user is logged in without logging it again?

Thanks!

Comment: This is far to broad... telling us which service and protocols you want to use would begin to narrow it down!

Comment: I want to know if i can call a web service that returns a message with a username and a flag indicating if he is authenticated or not. And then, in my app use that user to provide to asp.net identity. is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET 4.5.1 make integration with external authentication services easier for developers by providing built-in integration for the authentication services such as `Facebook, Google, Microsoft Accounts and Twitter`. Otherwise your web application can enable users to log in using `OAuth 2.0`  with credentials from an external authentication.

Comment: I will try harder! i don't want google, facebook or twitter login. i have a external webservice that returns username and a boolean indicating that a user is authenticated or not. In my app i only receive that information. Is it possible to initialize asp.net identity with that information?